# Stylesheets directory not added to load path for Compass extension

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to create a basic Compass extension, following the docs here:
http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

The problem I'm seeing is that I can't import files from my extension as expected, because the stylesheets directory, which the docs say will be automatically added onto the load path, isn't being added to the load path.

It gives me a command line error saying it can't find the file I tried to import, then lists out the load paths, verifying that my path is not on there.

One of the load paths is indeed /Users/myname/Sites/sitename/myextension_name, but I would expect there to also be /Users/myname/Sites/sitename/myextension_name/**stylesheets**

Anyone know why this wouldn't be happening as indicated in the docs?

**UPDATE**
Here's my config.rb as requested:

```
add_import_path '../../myextension'

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require "susy"
require "sass-media_query_combiner"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "../../js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
output_style = :expanded #or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = false
```

Comment: This is an ad hoc extension. I'm just trying to create a simple reusable base with a couple stylesheets placed in the stylesheets directory as defined in the docs linked above. I've output my config.rb above if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad hoc extensions need to be placed within the `extensions_dir` directory (which is set to `extensions` by default).

```
/path/to/config.rb
/path/to/sass/
/path/to/stylesheets/
/path/to/extensions/ <- extensions go here
```

Your `myextension_name` extension should live in `/path/to/extensions/myextension_name/` and then follow the rest of the conventions for creating an extension.  You may be able to assign `extensions_dir` to be the same as your `sass_dir` or your project's root, but I'm not sure that would be a wise idea.

If your extension is meant to be reused with other projects, it might be better to bundle it as a gem instead and use it the same way you're using Susy.